# "Low Reorder for Structure" plugin - links to the wrong reorder list

Tags: structure, low-reorder

Do any of you use the [Low Reorder for Structure](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-reorder-for-structure) plugin?

Assuming you're using Structure & Low Reorder, it adds a link next to a page which has listings, and changes the "Add or Edit" link to be "Add, Edit or Reorder."

I'm having a problem where the "Reorder" link is going to the wrong reorder list. And the unfortunate part is that it matches up reorder lists to listings automatically, so I can't manually select one or the other (as far as I know).

I've got two reorder lists that pull from the same channel. The channel is called "projects" and the lists are called "projects" and "area" - Projects is all of the listings, while area is a particular subset.

According to the docs, it should pick up the reorder list with the same name, but it's picking up the other one instead.

Is there a way to override the selection that the plugin is making? Or change my data to get the plugin to select the right list?

EDIT: After some testing, it looks like it uses the last reorder list that uses the same channel. I deleted my first 'projects' list and recreated it, and then it was working. Delete the 'area' one and recreate it, and then it links to that. It's not a fix, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is caused by both sets using the same listing.

The copy on the Low Reorder for Structure plugin page suggests that the listings need to be unique for this to work correctly. That's how I'm reading it.

> This accessory will **look for structure listings that are using Low
>   Reorder sets**. If it finds a match it will add a "Reorder" link next to
>   the "Add or Edit" links.

To change the default functionality, you'd need to hack the addon.

Comment: Hmm... I thought it was doing some name matching. I wonder if it's just picking it up out of the template file...

Comment: I think it's matching on the channel that is used in the listing and the Reorder... I'm not 100% sure but that's how I interpret the copy I posted above. Best to dig into the Addon code to see exactly.

Comment: I messed with it a bit. It looks like it uses the last reorder list that matches the listing channel for the page. So I deleted the list and recreated it, and now the reorder button points to the right spot.

Comment: Try http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/streeng with allow="none" set